# Checking the time difference between boolean values

Tags: c#, stopwatch

I've got a Boolean value called `isPressed` which is active when all keyboard and mouse buttons are active. What I want to achieve is when the `isPressed` Boolean value is `true` to start a timer (preferably using the Stopwatch class). While `isPressed` is true keep the timer going and as soon as `isPressed` is `false` then stop the timer and get the difference. After it's stopped and it's true again and then stops again, add the difference to the previous timer.

I tried to use the code from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767561/timer-c-start-stop-and-get-the-amount-of-time-between-the-calls) but I couldn't get it to work. I tried doing something like:

```
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
if (isPressed)
{
    stopWatch.Start();
}
else
{
    stopWatch.Stop();
    string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds / 10);
    lblTime.Text = string.Format("{0}", elapsedTime);
}
```

The `lblTime` label always stayed at 0.

Comment: Specifically, show where isPressed is assigned.  That is where you will want to start/stop your timer.

Comment: Perhaps you should make `stopWatch` global and construct it only once (when `isPressed` is true).

Comment: @EricJ. isPressed is assigned in KeyDown and MouseDown events.

Comment: Then that is where you should start/stop your timer.  The solution proposed by @RobCroll seems reasonable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually managed to get it to work thanks to @Andrey Nasonov, All I have to do was actually set `Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();` global.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking a stopwatch is maybe an unnecessary overhead.  You could mark the time isPressed is set to true and the time isPressed is set to false and then do the calculation.

```
    private long _pressedTicks;
    private long _durationTicks;

    private bool _pressed;

    public bool Pressed
    {
        get { return _pressed; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _pressed)
            {
                //Do nothing;
            }
            else if (value == false)
            {
                _durationTicks = DateTime.Now.Ticks - _pressedTicks;
                _pressed = value;
            }
            else
            {
                _pressed = value;
                _pressedTicks = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Note: Call `Pressed = true` or `Pressed = false` as appropriate from your KeyDown and MouseDown event handlers.