# C# how to measure elapsed time?

Tags: c#, elapsedtime

I want to record the amount of time it takes to execute my custom method, but I have never worked with the timer class or methods before, I know I'm doing something wrong,
.

Here's what I have.

```
System.Timers.Timer Time;
int Mili = 0 ;

data = Generate();

Time.Enabled = true;
BSort= BubbleSort(data);

Time.Enabled = false;
```

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate the execution time of a method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14019510/calculate-the-execution-time-of-a-method)

Comment: Or a possible duplicate of [How do I measure how long a function is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107140/how-do-i-measure-how-long-a-function-is-running)

Answer (score 10):

A timer is for a periodic event. You should look at the [`Stopwatch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

```
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

// your code ...

// sw.Stop(), sw.Elapsed, etc.
```