# How to get Total Time of a call from a webtestrequest

Tags: c#

I have a web performance test that logs into a website.
Once the test is complete the results table in VS displays a total time column.
I have generated the code and would like to get this total time value programmatically. How do I achieve this?

This is not a duplicate to "how can I tell how long a function has been running?". I can do this.

When you run a web performance test the results are displayed and there is a column titled total time. I want to get this total time programmatically. I am assuming there is a variable somewhere that I can get this value from. I hope this helps.

Comment: Sum up the values

Comment: Can you read values from each row of this column and add them up?

Comment: I want to automate this

Answer (score 1):

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [How do I measure how long a function is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107140/how-do-i-measure-how-long-a-function-is-running)

You achieve this with the **System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch** class :

```
var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
// the code that you want to measure comes here
watch.Stop();
var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

**Source** : [Calculate the execution time of a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14019510/calculate-the-execution-time-of-a-method)